# Add text on mobile layout only

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my website's [mobile version](http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://ddc.ge)
I want to add small text 'MENU' [here](http://www.picz.ge/img/s3/1606/28/4/4a4ca1d5b880.jpg)

When I try to add here it is visible in desktop version too.

```
<div id="responsive-menu-container">
            <span class="menu">MENU</span>
            </div>
```

How to add this text in mobile version only?
Or maybe not the code, but the way I try to add is incorrect?

Comment: You can make it, so it would only appear from a specific resolution. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp Read more here

Answer (score 7):

You can hide or show it with `@media` tags with css. Like this:

Your normal css class:

```
.menu{
   display:none;
}
```

Your mobile version class:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu{
       display:block;
    }
}
```

After that by using your example, you have to put "menu" span inside your "responsive-menu-container". After adding it, you can adjust its position.

```
<div id="responsive-menu-container">
   <span class="menu">MENU</span> 
</div>
```

Edit for `position:absolute` :

If you are using a reference library for menu bar and creating this content with automatically, you can also use `position:absolute` for `.menu` class. Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.menu {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999; /* I gave this value because your menu bar's z-index must be smaller than this. */
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works. Big thx. But now, how to place it above the blue rectangle like on screenshot?! `margin: -20px, 0px, 0px 0px!important;` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks but I can't find this div <div class="mean-bar"> in my files using Notepad+

Comment: Any help?! There is no mean-bar div in my files.

Comment: I think you used a reference library to create mobile menu bar and it creates mean-bar div automatically. You can also do it with "position:absolute;". I have updated my answer for it.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand where can I add your code. There is my navigation code`<!-- Main Navigation -->
                <nav class="main-menu">
                    <?php 
                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                        'container' => false,
                        'menu_class' => 'header-nav clearfix'
                    ));
                    ?>
                </nav>

                <div id="responsive-menu-container">
</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: 1- Delete "@media only screen and (max-width: 530px)
.mean-container .mean-bar .mean-nav {
    margin-top: 13px;
}", 2- Place your span between this div <div id="responsive-menu-container"><span class="menu">MENU</span> </div>, 3- Add my position:absolute edit: "@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.menu {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}"

Comment: It works, but now it is visible in desktop version again. `.menu {
   display:none!important;
}` will hide it for mobile version too.

Comment: You can fix it with adding "display:block!important" in mobile .menu class too.